# iPhone: how to work with this NSArray

Tags: iphone

in my NSArray contains below info like **userName, screenName, Description etc**

this information i have to **display on simulator r device with respectively UIElements **

whether i have to keep the NSArray in NSDictionary if so how i have to do that can you tell me how to work with this

i am using this delegate and getting below info on console

```
-(void)userInfoReceived:(NSArray *)userInfo forRequest:(NSString *)connectionIdentifier {
    NSLog(@"User Info Received: %@", userInfo);
}
```

this is info in **Debug Console**

```
{

"created_at" = "Fri Nov 19 17:22:47 +0000 2010";

description = "";

"favourites_count" = 0;

"followers_count" = 99;

following = 0;

"friends_count" = 860;

lang = en;

"listed_count" = 0;

location = "";

name = "preeti singh";

"profile_background_image_url" = "http://a3.twimg.com/a/1292606737/images/themes/theme1/bg.png";

 "profile_image_url" = "http://a2.twimg.com/a/1292531900/images/default_profile_6_normal.png";

 "profile_use_background_image" = true;

"screen_name" = preetisingjik;

}
```

Comment: Thank you i did it now answer me please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your signature suggest that a NSArray should be passed in while obviously, a NSDictionary is instead !

I suggest you change the protocol to

```
 (void)userInfoReceived:(NSArray *)userInfo forRequest:(NSString *)connectionIdentifier
```

Then access the value from your dictionary using

```
NSString *desc = [userInfo objectForKey:@"description"];
```

Comment: hi VdesmedT, when i directly searching in NSArray with NSString, i got WARING's and its not working, now NSArray values i have to keep in NSDictionary and Searching with objectForKey:@"name" , one more thing is i can search directly string with NSArray(it won't works right).here NSString *desc = [userInfo objectForKey:@"description"]; we are searching in Array with string.  Please tell me

Comment: @Nandakishore, don't just accept answers so somebody would answer you.